# Class Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: laravel-7, php-7.4

I am trying to use Laravel Jobs, and that worked for few times but now I am getting this error.

> Class Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods
>
> "message": "Class Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher::findBatch, Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher::batch, Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher::dispatchSync)",
> "exception": "Symfony\Component\ErrorHandler\Error\FatalError",
> "file": "D:\xampp8\htdocs\sa-new\laravel-develop\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher.php",
> "line": 13,

My controller code looks like this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Database\QueryException;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Response;

use App\Model\BccMapping;
use App\Jobs\ProcessUnmappedRequests;

public function processUnmappedRequests(Request $request){            
            ProcessUnmappedRequests::dispatch('3',$request);
    }
```

While my Job's code looks like this.

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use App\Model\BccMapping;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;


class ProcessUnmappedRequests implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;
    protected $request;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($id, $request)
    {
        $this->siteId = $request->get('siteId');
        $this->mappingId = $request->get('mappingId');
        $this->email = $request->get('originEmail');
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       $unmappedRequests =  DB::table('bcc')->where("EmailFrom", trim($this->email))->whereNull('BccMappingId')
                                        ->where('Archive',0)->get();
       if($unmappedRequests->isNotEmpty()){
           $mapping = BccMapping::where('id',$this->mappingId )->first();
           if(!$mapping)
               return false;
           $mappingData = json_decode($mapping->mapping);
           $keyword = $mapping->keyword;
           foreach ($unmappedRequests as $key=>$bcc){

               $bccKeyword = app('App\Http\Controllers\BccToolController')->getDomNodeValue($mappingData->keywordPath->path,$bcc->HTML);
               var_dump($bccKeyword);die;
           }
       }else{
           return false;
       }
    }
}
```

Currently I am using Laravel 7.0 and PHP 7.4.

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: The error message you are getting is quite explicit - you need to implement all the methods in the contract, and you have not done so. There are three missing, listed in your error. Do you know what these methods should do? I would guess that it is documented.

Comment: @halfer I have followed this link [link](https://laravel-news.com/laravel-jobs-and-queues-101)and it has not implemented any methods. can you tell me how and which methods i have to implement?

Comment: They are in your error message: `findBatch`, `batch`, `dispatchSync`.