# Laravel Queue : Class Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the remaining methods

Tags: laravel-7, laravel-queue

I was trying to add Queue to one of my existing Laravel projects. I have tried different tutorials related to queuing in Laravel such as [this](https://www.itsolutionstuff.com/post/how-to-create-queue-with-mail-in-laravel-5-example.html). I have created a fresh Laravel project and tried this and it was working fine. I have found that this question has already been asked before in Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64323158/class-illuminate-bus-dispatcher-contains-3-abstract-methods-and-must-therefore-b), but I couldn't find any solution posted there. Any help is highly appreciated.
Below are the codes :

EmployeesController.php

```
....
dispatch(new EmployeeListExportJob(['data'=>$data,'countries'=>$countries,'format'=>$request->format]));
....
```

EmployeeListExportJob.php

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Excel;
use App\Exports\EmployeesExportExcel;

class EmployeeListExportJob implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;


    protected $details;
    protected $data;
    protected $countries;
    protected $format;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($details)
    {
        $this->data = $details['data'];
        $this->countries = $details['countries'];
        $this->format = $details['format'];
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
        Excel::download(new EmployeesExportExcel($this->data, $this->countries), 'Employees.xlsx');
    }
}
```

I tried a **custom dispatcher class**, **custom queue class** and also I have tried adding the missing methods (**findBatch**,**batch**,**dispatchSync**) inside the **EmployeeListExportJob class**. But nothing worked.

I got the same error :
**Class Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the missing methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher::findBatch, Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher::batch, Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher::dispatchSync)**

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, you're asking us to answer questions about code that we cannot see, which is clearly very difficult. I'd suggest you go back to re-read the [help] pages, especially [ask] and [mre], and then [edit] your question to comply with those requirements.

Comment: Sorry for that. this is my first post.

Comment: "it was working fine" - so what's the problem you're facing? Any error you could share? If yes, please also share your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: Also, please keep in mind that Laravel 7 is EOL since years. You should update it to a supported version

Comment: It works in a fresh Laravel installation, but not working with the existing project. I tried a custom dispatcher class, custom queue class and also I have tried adding the missing methods (findBatch,batch,dispatchSync) inside the EmployeeListExportJob class. But nothing worked. I got the same error : Class Illuminate\Bus\Dispatcher contains 3 abstract methods and must therefore be declared abstract or implement the missing methods (Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher::findBatch, Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\QueueingDispatcher::batch, Illuminate\Contracts\Bus\Dispatcher::dispatchSync)

Comment: Please add all clarification **to your question** by editing it. Also, if the error message asks you to implement these methods, why not do that?

Comment: Hi, as I mentioned in the previous comment, I have tried that too.

Comment: I have edited the question. Thank you for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was automatically fixed after updating the Laravel version from 7 to Laravel 8.